# What would cause this behavior in only one person's IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gradient, internet-explorer-8

Stack Overflow won't let me post my whole question because I'm an untrusted new user, so if you're interested in this question please visit
http://doctype.com/would-cause-behavior-only-one-persons-ie8

> The backgrounds in question are drawn
>   with a single-pixel, xy-repeated,
>   semitransparent PNG.
>
> This person's IE8 is drawing this as a
>   gradient that starts at the top left
>   corner and becomes more transparent to
>   the right and below.
>
> I am unable to reproduce this problem
>   in IE8/WinXP/VMwareFusion/SnowLeopard.
>   Also cannot reproduce with IE7 (IE8 in
>   compatibility mode). Also cannot
>   reproduce with IE6 or any other
>   browser.
>
> we are running the same version --
>   only the product IDs are different.
>
> I confirmed at
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8#Release_history
>   that 18702 is a final release version
>   of IE8.
>
> Even tho I did not think it would
>   help, I asked for a list of addons in
>   IE8 -- nothing unusual.
>
> What could be causing this problem for
>   just this one person? The person
>   mentioned that it is a work computer
>   and the IT people are really strict
>   about things. Could any workplace
>   restrictions cause this weird
>   behavior? Could it be a graphics
>   driver issue?
>
> Again, I know this is not an IE8
>   problem because I have IE8 and cannot
>   reproduce it.
>
> I want to know how might one alter IE8
>   -- perhaps for security reasons -- so that this behavior is seen? Or, what
>   would cause one specific computer to
>   display things this way?

Comment: You should add in the description of the problem here - that certain installs of IE8 are turning single pixel repeated background images into a gradient that fades from the image color in the top left to transparent on the bottom right.

Comment: For anyone with the knowledge to help: The question at the link is well-formulated and he's done what research he can.  It's a display issue with IE8 where the only known difference is in the Product ID shown in the IE8 about box.

Comment: FYI I have seen the same behavior in IE7.

Comment: Are there multiple CSS files for the site? Could be possible that corporate firewall is blocking 1 of the style sheets for some reason?

Comment: On your site, is the background of the "School of Pharmacy" header supposed to fade? In IE7 I am seeing a vertical gradient on it, and the same gradient you noted (top left to bottom right) on the side menu buttons and sub menus off of the horizontal menu under the "School of Pharmacy" header.

Comment: jball: For details about why I was unable to post my entire question, see http://www.facebook.com/#!/frankfarm?v=wall&story_fbid=504248921236&ref=mf (I believe this is a public page, but let me know if you find otherwise.)

Eric J.: Thanks much!

jaywon: Good suggestion, thx - I tried commenting out each CSS file in turn but was still unable to reproduce the problem. I also tried with various JS files with no luck.

Comment: jball: No, the bkgd of the School of Pharmacy header is not supposed to fade -- http://pharmacy.ucsf.edu/2010/05/19/ucsf1.jpg is what it should look like.

D_N: Noted, thanks. I clarified what I meant about IE7, but your comment does not seem to help explain what might be happening. I will look for and set up IE7 standalone nonetheless - this is worth doing, so thanks.

Comment: @Frank, just noticed your comment with the facebook link, unfortunately facebook is blocked by the corporate filter for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered this problem before and the only solution I found is not to use a 1x1 pixel image. Try 1x10 it should fix it.

Comment: I could try this, but I am doubtful because this doesn't explain why one person sees the problem and no one else does. And when we compare browser versions they are exactly the same.

Comment: I can reproduce it on my computer. We could try and see if we can pinpoint the problem. Also, using the developer tools, I tested and using a larger image works correctly on my comp.

Answer (score 0):

Are any files (graphics, js, css) being pulled from a server that might be blocked by their office firewall?

I've had this happen, where just one graphic was from some off-limits site, with bizarre results.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using jQuery, and this bug will pop-up on mouseover for random IE7 and IE8 users. I found one possible fix in a [www.farmcode.org blog post](http://www.farmcode.org/post/2010/03/26/jQuery-fade-bug-in-IE-e28093-background-transparent-PNG-image.aspx):

Wrap the body of your page with the following conditional:

```
<!--[if IE]><div id="ieWrap"><![endif]—>

(the rest of the page html goes here)

<!--[if IE]></div><![endif]—>
```

and add the following CSS for IE:

```
#ieWrap .productView .productThumbnail a
{        
  background-image: none;        
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader
                 (src='grey_overlay.png',sizingMethod='scale');
  width:100%;
}
```

You'll need to change the CSS to match your situation, but this should get you started.

Comment: See also the multi-body hack ( http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ )

Comment: @fforw - nice, seems like a relatively clean hack.

Comment: jball: Thank you! I could try this, but I am doubtful because this doesn't explain why one person sees the problem and no one else does. And when we compare browser versions they are exactly the same. The farmcode.org blog post describes my problem exactly, but its bug demo page does not demonstrate the problem for me -- I am unable to reproduce it in IE8. (One commenter also said he was unable to reproduce in IE7/Win2008Server on 3-26-2010.) When I click the Test Fade button, the 2nd box disappears and a single solid gray box remains, which is not what the blog post says will happen.

Comment: @Frank, when I have seen this problem, it's been on both IE7 and 8 on random browsers, so you not being able to replicate it on your installation of IE is unsurprising. Your best best is to find a user/install with the problem, and see if they would be willing to test any solutions you try on a set of test pages. I actually see some of the problems on my IE7 browser here as well, and would be willing to be a guinea pig if you post test links of the solutions.

Comment: @jball: it's especially nice that it does not generate additional requests like IE specific stylesheets do. 

And you can keep your CSS better organized

Comment: @Frank, have the user who sent you the screenshots go to the farmcode blog post and try the fade. I'm pretty sure they'll see the fade.